# Phone field validation using Jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, regex

I would like to allow a user to input his mobile number in the following format:

> +66 798644356

or

> 798644356

So basically with country code or without. Also I would like to allow Open and close brackets ()

I first started with doing the code below to just limit numeric numbers however than i noticed that this is not the right approach because it stops you from using a + sign and also brackets ():

```
        $('#signup-phone-number , #signup-mobile-number').keyup( function() {
           $(this).numeric();
        });
```

I have read that you can use a regular expression, however I am new to this. I did some google search and this is the regex I want to use:

> ^((+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}98(\s){0,1}(-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$

the problem is how I have to implement this in jquery?

Comment: Search for 'regex phone' on SO or Google.

Answer (score 1):

Below regex can match any type of number, remember, I have assumed `+` to be optional.
However it does not handle number counting

```
^\+?(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d$
```

Here are some valid numbers you can match:

```
+91293227214
+3 313 205 55100
99565433
011 (103) 132-5221
+1203.458.9102
+134-56287959
(211)123-4567
111-123-4567
```

Answer (score 1):

For validation, I generally use [jQuery Validator Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Here is a custom rule for UK phone numbers:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('ukPhone', function(value, element){
        return value.match(/^((\(44\))( )?|(\(\+44\))( )?|(\+44)( )?|(44)( )?)?((0)|(\(0\)))?( )?(((1[0-9]{3})|(7[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2})|(20)( )?[7-8]{1})( )?([0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3})|(2[0-9]{2}( )?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}))$/);
}, 'Enter a valid phone number');
```

How to use the plugin with custom rules:

```
jQuery('#form-id').validate({
     rules: {
        telephone: {
           required: true,
           ukPhone: true
        }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all non-numeric characters and the country code (+66) with nothing, then check if the length of the number that remains is correct.

```
var normalized_input = input.replace( "+66", "" ).replace( /[^\d]/g, "" );
if( normalized_input.length == 10 ) {
  console.log( "Yay! This is a valid phone number" );
}
```

Normalizing the input will make it easier to use the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

**regex** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3SHQC/1/)

```
$('#phn_num').blur(function () {
    var reg = /(\+66)?( )?[0-9]{9}/;
    if(reg.test($(this).val())){
        alert('correct');
    }
});
```

Supports both `+66 798644356` and `798644356`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3SHQC/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="phn_num" />
```

**js**

```
$('#phn_num').attr('maxlength','9');

$('#phn_num').keypress(function (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) return false;

    return true;
});
```